# Defining colour if index contains certain string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe (for example)

```
          Value
Sample_A_1  5
Sample_B    1
Sample_A_2  2
Sample_D    3
Sample_F    4
```

and wish to run `df['Value'].plot(kind='bar')`
If I want to define a colour for the bar whenever the index string contains `Sample_A` and other colours for other samples, how would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is create dictionary for specify colors by values contains index, then [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) values and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html), add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.fillna.html) for specify default color (if no value match) and last pass to parameter `color`:

```
colors = {'Sample_A': 'r', 'Sample_B': 'b', 'Sample_D': 'g'}
pat = (r'({})'.format('|'.join(colors.keys())))
c = df.index.str.extract(pat,expand=False).map(colors.get).fillna('y')

df['Value'].plot(kind='bar', color=c)
```

[image: graph]

Another solution is add new column for colors by looping by dictionary with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
for k, v in colors.items():
    df.loc[df.index.str.contains(k), 'color'] = v
print (df)
            Value color
Sample_A_1      5     r
Sample_B        1     b
Sample_A_2      2     r
Sample_D        3     g
Sample_F        4   NaN

df['Value'].plot(kind='bar', color=df['color'].fillna('y'))
```

Comment: `df.index.str.extract(pat,expand=False).map(colors.get).fillna('y')` I am just wondering if there is some less verbose way to do it?

Comment: @Bazingaa - Hmmm, thank you for comment, what do you think about alternative in modified answer?

Comment: Much better and readable. Thanks for the modification